# Common Lisp -- List unpacking? (similar to Python)

Tags: python, list, lisp, common-lisp, iterable-unpacking

In Python, assuming the following function is defined:

```
def function(a, b, c):
    ... do stuff with a, b, c ...
```

I am able to use the function using Python's sequence unpacking:

```
arguments = (1, 2, 3)
function(*arguments)
```

Does similar functionality exist in Common Lisp? So that if I have a function:

```
(defun function (a b c)
    ... do stuff with a, b, c ...
```

And if I have a list of 3 elements, I could easily use those 3 elements as parameters to the function?

The way I currently implement it is the following:

```
(destructuring-bind (a b c) (1 2 3)
    (function a b c))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Note that there is `,@` which is similar. For example, `(let ((x '(2 3))) \`(1 ,@x 4 5))` becomes `(1 2 3 4 5)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`apply`](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Bby4FJy49QUC&lpg=PA61&ots=0tuzZ3zG1J&dq=lisp%20argument%20unpacking&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Note that this only works when the function's only arguments are contained in the list.  Otherwise, `destructuring-bind` is needed, and matches python's ability to do `function(*args, another_arg)`.

Answer (score 23):

Use the [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm) function:

```lisp
(apply #'function arguments)
```

Example:

```lisp
CL-USER> (apply #'(lambda (a b c) (+ a b c)) '(1 2 3))
6
```